# Why it is called the Memberwise Initialiser

Tags: swift, initializer

Quote from the [office Swift Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID82)

> All structure have an automatically-generated **memberwise initializer**, which you can use to initialize the member properties of new structure instances ...

**Question 1**: What is so special about the default initializer, why can't it be simply called the default initializer? Why adding the "memberwise"?  Is it because it lists out all the member properties defined in the Structure. And you also have to follow the order defined inside the Structure when creating an instance.

**Question 2** Is there any other special initializers who have their own special name? If so, what they look like.

[Note Part I:] For further discuss with Mr. Vadian

[image]

[Note Part II:]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding question 1:

There is an irrevocable law in Swift:

> Classes and **structures** must set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or **structure** is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.

We are talking about **structs**:

When creating a **struct** you *can* use the **default initializer** (the pair of parentheses) if all properties have a default value.

If you just declare the properties without a default value, the compiler creates an implicit **memberwise initializer** – which you *have to* use – to make sure to assign a default value to each property in a very convenient way

Comment: Thanks a lot! Vadian. So the compiler only creates an Implicit memberwise initializer to notice you what to create in the proper and correct way.

Comment: I think I understand a little bit what you said. If I create a Structure without creating any default value for the properties. When I create an instance of that Structure, the compiler will automatically generate a  "memberwise initializer" notice for me. (Please see the note part of the question)

Comment: Yes, exactly, but it's not really a notice, it's just a suggestion how to fulfill the requirements

Comment: Not notice,,hmmm.. and is is called the **implicit** Memberwise initialzer.. Makes a lot of sense for me now! Thanks so much, Always can learn staff from your guys' help!

Comment: It's only called **memberwise initializer**

Comment: I think if I declare the properties with a default value it can also generate the memberwise initializer (please see the note part II) . Hence, it then has a default initializer `test() ` and the memberwise initializer 'test(a: Int, b: Int)'

Comment: Yes, the memberwise initializer is created also in this case to be able to assign custom different values easily.

Answer (score 2):

This seems primarily opinion based, and not a good fit for SO, but here's my 2 cents:

1. *Default* sounds a lot like *Designated*, which is a completely orthogonal concept.
2. Not "special", but there are at least 2 different kinds of initializers: [*designated* and *convenience*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID216).

Comment: Thanks. I haven't heard anything bout the designated and convenience initializer. Good to know that they do exist and what they called. More staff to learn now ")

Comment: If you feel this answer satisfies your question, please accept it :)

Comment: Designated and convenience initializers are only for classes. This question was in regards to a struct.

Comment: @LeeGillen Even still, it would leading to confusing terminology.