# How to use Swift struct implicit initializer?

Tags: swift

Here is the code I have:

```
struct Algorithm {
    let category: String = ""
    let title: String = ""
    let fileName: String = ""
}

let a = Algorithm(
```

The autocomplete shows the only valid initializer:

[image]

But I was expecting to use the implicit initializer like

```
Algorithm(category: "", title: "", fileName: "")
```

This gives the error:

> Argument passed to call that takes no arguments

There are even [screenshots on another issue that shows this call being successfully used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38001021/why-it-is-called-the-memberwise-initialiser/38001343#38001343).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the `let`. If you declare your properties with `var`, you'll get the memberwise initializer:

```
struct Algorithm {
    var category: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    var fileName: String = ""
}
let alg = Algorithm(category: "", title: "", fileName: "")
```

But since you supplied default values for all the properties, you don't get the memberwise initializer for `let` properties. The rule is that you get the implicit memberwise initializer for stored properties without a default value and for `var` properties (provided you have no explicit declared initializer).

Answer (score 5):

You provided the default values for the properties that's why compiler won't add the default initialiser. When you remove the default values you will get what you are expecting:

```
struct Algorithm {
    let category: String
    let title: String
    let fileName: String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
struct Algorithm {
    var category: String = ""
    var title: String = ""
    var fileName: String = ""
}
```

and autocomplete will show you both possibilities